# AngularJS: How to prevent "code flash" in page while loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zurb-foundation, fouc

I have created a simple app using AngularJS. When I open the page for a second I see the screen below:

[image]

However, after the load is complete I see the loaded and styled content which is fine:

[image]

How do I prevent the flash of AngularJS code on my page ? Is this related to FOUC ?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" ng-app="MainApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation | Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>

    <style>
    .row.full-width {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        max-width: initial;
    }
    </style>

</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            <nav class="tab-bar">
                <section class="right-small">
                    <a class="right-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" href="#"><span></span></a>
                </section>
                <section class="left tab-bar-section">
                    <h1 class="title">Salary Calculator</h1>
                </section>
            </nav>

            <aside class="right-off-canvas-menu">
                <ul class="off-canvas-list">
                    <li>
                        <label>Location</label>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">United Kingdom</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </aside>

            <section class="main-section">


                <div class="row full-width">
                    <div class="large-4 columns">

                        <ul class="tabs" data-tab>
                            <li class="tab-title active"><a href="#panel1">Annual Salary</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2">Monthly Expenses</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="tabs-content">
                            <div class="content active" id="panel1">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="large-12 columns">
                                        <input ng-change="calculate()" type="text" placeholder="Salary" ng-model="salary"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content" id="panel2">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="large-4 columns">
                                        <input ng-change="calculate()" type="text" placeholder="Rent" ng-model="rent" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="large-4 columns">
                                        <input ng-change="calculate()" type="text" placeholder="Wireless, TV, Home Phone" ng-model="telecom"/>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="large-4 columns">
                                        <input ng-change="calculate()" type="text" placeholder="TV License" ng-model="tv" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="large-4 columns">
                                        <input ng-change="calculate()" type="text" placeholder="Mobile Phone" ng-model="mobile"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="large-4 columns">
                                        <input ng-change="calculate()" type="text" placeholder="Subscription" ng-model="subscription"/>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="large-4 columns">
                                        <input ng-change="calculate()" type="text" placeholder="Electricty" ng-model="electricity" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="large-4 columns">
                                        <input ng-change="calculate()" type="text" placeholder="Food" ng-model="food"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="large-4 columns">
                                        <input ng-change="calculate()" type="text" placeholder="Transport" ng-model="transport" />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="large-4 columns">
                                        <input ng-change="calculate()" type="text" placeholder="Charity" ng-model="charity"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="large-12 columns">
                                        <input ng-change="calculate()" type="text" placeholder="Other" ng-model="other"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="large-8 columns"  ng-cloak >
                        <table >
                       <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="200"></th>
                                <th width="250">Yearly</th>
                                <th width="250">Monthly</th>
                                <th width="250">Weekly</th>
                                <th width="250">Daily</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody ng-repeat="val in results">
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{val.rowType}}</td>
                                <td>{{val.yearly}}</td>
                                <td>{{val.monthly}}</td>
                                <td>{{val.weekly}}</td>
                                <td>{{val.daily}}</td>

                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                </div>



            </section>

            <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="../bower_components/angularjs/angular.js"></script>


    <script src="js/app-service.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app-controller.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app-directives.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).foundation();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

***EDIT:***

Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34255687/586986) as well for an alternative solution in addition to the accepted one.

Comment: Can you post the code relevant to it ? I would say use ng-bind instead of using expressions like {{}}.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

ng-cloak will help to some extent, but you can fully prevent it using ng-bind directive instead of using `{{ }}`.

e.g.

```
<td ng-bind="val.monthly"> </td>
```

not

```
<td>{{val.monthly}}</td>
```

Comment: This has another advantage, namely that you can provide some default text until the template is loaded. E.g. `<h1 ng-bind="title">Loading...</h1>`

Answer (score 5):

It has been a long time but here is for my working solution for this one:

You need to use `ng-cloak` on the body tag of your html BUT the most important part is this CSS below:

`[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}`

For me I had to add this for getting ng-cloak to work. This is probably not the only solution to this problem as can be seen in other answers. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: In addition to adding the CSS style, I needed to add the ng-clock directive to the element housing my ng-app directive: <div ng-cloak ng-app="my-app">

Answer (score 4):

Angular already gives you the tool to prevent this: `ngCloak`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Just put the directive on your body like `<body ng-cloak>` and it should work.

**EDIT**
The Docs also advice you to actually not put it on the body, but on smaller portions of your page - wherever you see the need. Depending on the size of your page, that is a good idea. For smaller Pages I put it on the body and never had problems.

Comment: Thanks. This made the transition quicker but did not completely solve it unfortunately. I still see the code.

Answer (score 4):

Along with `ng-cloak`, you can use a `resolve object` in your router. This will prevent the controller from instantiating and the view from rendering until the data is there.

In the following example I am assuming you are using `uiRouter`. The same pattern applies for `ngRouter`.

Your state config:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('yourState',{
        templateUrl: 'yourTemplate.html',
        controller: 'YourController as vm',
        resolve: YourController.resolve
    })
```

As you can see, you have set the resolve property of the state to a static resolve object on your controller. Now the route will not resolve until this object is resolved.

To setup resolve object, lets assume you have a service `yourService` that has a method `getData` that returns a promise. This is very important. Because we **don't want the route resolved until the promise is resolved**.

So your controller may look something like this.

```
YourController.$inject = ['yourService'];
function YourController(yourService) {
    var self = this;
    yourService.getData().then((data) { self.data = data});
}
```

This is pretty standard. You can access the data from the view with `vm.data` but you will see a flash of `{{vm.data}}`. That is, if we remove the resolve we have added to the state config.

So now we change the controller to add a static resolve object to work with the `resolve` we have added to the state config.

```
YourController.resolve = {
    'yourService': 'yourService',
    'data': ['yourService', function(yourService) {
        return yourService.getData();    
    }]
}

YourController.$inject = ['data'];
function YourController(data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

So now we have a resolve object. The `yourService` will resolve as a normal service, but the `data` property will resolve only when the promise returned by `getData()` is resolved. Then this `data` will be passed directly into the controller using Dependancy Injection.

In reality, you probably wont need to use `ng-cloak` if you use `resolve`.

Here is a working example:

```js
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])

.config(['$stateProvider',
  function($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    
      .state('noDot', {
        controller: "NoDotController",
        template: "Using a old style $scope binding {{customers[0].CutomerName}}"
      })
             
      .state('noResolve', {
        controller: "NoResolveController as vm",
        template: "We are displaying things before the data is here {{vm.customers[0].CustomerName}}"
      })

    .state('withResolve', {
      controller: "WithResolveController as vm",
      template: "We are waiting for data before displaying anything {{vm.customers[0].CustomerName}}",
      resolve: WithResolveController.resolve
    })

    .state('empty', {
      template: ""
    })

  }
])

.controller('NoResolveController', NoResolveController)
  .controller('NoDotController', NoDotController)
  .controller('WithResolveController', WithResolveController)
  .service('northwind', Northwind);

NoDotController.$inject = ['$scope', 'northwind'];
function NoDotController($scope, northwind) {
  northwind.getCustomers().then(function(customers) {
    $scope.customers = customers});
}

NoResolveController.$inject = ['northwind'];
function NoResolveController(northwind) {
  var self = this;
  northwind.getCustomers().then(function(customers) {
    self.customers = customers;
  });
}

WithResolveController.resolve = {
  'northwind': 'northwind',
  'customers': ['northwind',
    function(northwind) {
      return northwind.getCustomers();
    }
  ]
}
WithResolveController.$inject = ['customers'];
function WithResolveController(customers) {
  this.customers = customers;
}

Northwind.$inject = ['$timeout', '$q'];
function Northwind($timeout, $q) {
  this.$q = $q;
  this.$timeout = $timeout;
}
Northwind.prototype.getCustomers = function() {
  var deferred = this.$q.defer();

  this.$timeout(function() {
    deferred.resolve([{CustomerName: "Name of Customer"}])
  }, 1000);

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.13/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <a ui-sref="noDot" href="#">No Dot</a>
  <span> | </span>
  <a ui-sref="empty" href="#">Emtpy</a>
  <span> | </span>
  <a ui-sref="noResolve" href="#">No Resolve</a>
  <span> | </span>
  <a ui-sref="empty" href="#">Emtpy</a>
  <span> | </span>
  <a ui-sref="withResolve" href="#">With Resolve</a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <ui-view></ui-view>

</div>
```