# How to avoid flickring of views using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `stateProvider` for routing.

**Problem:**

When I click any link, my controller calls the factory service recursively. What happens is that after every successful ajax call my view blinks or flickers. (Which I don't wan't)

Please provide some tips. So far I have tried `ng-cloak` and `class="ng-cloak"`, with no luck.

**Question:**
How can I avoid these flicker effect until all ajax calls are completed.

```
  .state('vehicle', {
      abstract:true,
      url: "/vehicle",
      template: '<div ui-view style="height:100%"></div>',          
      controller:'vehicleManagementCtrl'
  })
  .state('vehicle.list', {
        url: "",          
        templateUrl: 'views/br_manager/mg_vehicleManagement.html'
    })
  .state('vehicle.add', {
        url: "",
        templateUrl: 'views/br_manager/mg_addVehicle.html'
    })
  .state('vehicle.edit', {
      url: "",
      templateUrl: 'views/br_manager/mg_editVehicle.html'
  })
   .state('vehicle.delete', {
        url: "",
        templateUrl: 'views/br_manager/mg_addVehicle.html'
    })
```

Comment: Check 2nd answer - `resolve` when using `state` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514241/angularjs-how-to-prevent-code-flash-in-page-while-loading

Answer (score 0):

Try using `resolve` in your states, that way you can specify that an ajax call needs to be completed first in order to display the view. Try looking for more info on resolve in [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).

Answer (score 0):

This answer would probably fit better as a comment, but I can't do that yet.

Have you added the ng-cloak css classes in order to work?
Please check: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Do you make several requests on each click? I didn't get very well the recursivity.

Could you give an example or a fiddle so we can see the code?

Comment: when i click the link my controller calls fetchYearList()  after getting response i.e, 200 or 201 successive call is made  for zeroth $index  value  factory.fetchVehicleList = function(year){ return $resource (url+year,{},{ fetch: method: 'GET', header : 'application/json', intercepton : response(){ function(data) { return data }}})}